# Better approach handling: 'Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers' errors

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

**Beforehand**: My application is working as intended, but I want to know if there's an better approach to the problem, I was having.

**Situation**: I have a project where I am currently implemeneting a Permission-System. The current flow is, to load specific objects (lets take `user` in this case) and `inject` the permissions afterwards.

**Problem**: Getting *'Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.'* error inside vuex-action.

**Question:** Is there a better way to omit the error than my approach below?

Simplified it looks like this (here I am getting my objects from our API and storing them in vuex-store):

```
// user.js (vuex-module)
state: {
  user: null,
},
mutations: {
  // ... 
  setUser(state, user) {
      state.user = user
  }
}
actions: {
  // ... other vuex-actions
  async login({commit, dispatch}, payload) {
      let userFromDb = DbUtil.getUser(payload) // is an axios call to our api

      // here the permissions get injected
      // action in another vuex-module
      dispatch('permissions/injectPermissions', userFromDb)

      // commiting to store
      commit('setUser', userFromDb)

      return userFromDb
  }
}
```

My permissions.js (here I am injecting the permissions to my object):

```
// permissions.js (vuex-module)
actions: {
  // ... other vuex-actions

  // payload = user in this example
  async injectPermissions({commit, dispatch}, payload) {
      let permissionFromDb = DbUtil.getPermissions(/* ... */) 

      payload.permissions = permissionFromDb // -> Here I am getting 'Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.'-Error, because `payload` == the user from user-state

      return payload
  }
}
```

**Workaround**: I added a mutation which changes the user-state object for me inside a *mutation-handler*.

```
mutations: {
  /**
  * A 'set'-wrapper to mutate vuex-store variable inside a mutation to avoid getting a error.
  * @param state
  * @param payload:
  *   object - object to be mutated
  *   prop - prop inside object that is affected
  *   value - value that should be assigned
  */
  setWrapper(state, payload) {
   let { object, prop, value } = payload

   object[prop] = value
  }
}
```

The line where the error was thrown before gets changed to:

```
commit('setWrapper', {
  object: payload,
  prop: 'permissions',
  value: permissionFromDb
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actions do not mutate the state. 
Actions are there to perform asynchronous tasks. 
When you want to change the state within an action, you have to rely on a mutation by using this syntax: `commit('MUTATION_NAME', payload)`

Then:

```
MUATATION_NAME(state, payload) {
  state.permissions = payload.permissions
}
```

This is the cleanest and most correct way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of how the mutation - synchronous, actions - asynchronous thing works. My question was, if my approach was the cleanest way to do it, or if my approach was a quick and dirty way to eliminate the error I got.

Comment: Your approach is totally fine (it is the same as what I described above). But you can achieve the same using setters and getters.